# Hide a card after confirming in bootstrap modal on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

My delete page contains multiple post with delete button, when delete button is pressed bootstrap bootstrap modal opens and will ask for confirmation `are you sure you want to delete post ? YES : NO`

when `YES` button is pressed `.click(function (e){....}` sends `AJAX` request to database, if ajax return `success` that paticular card should be hidden

so i tried with following code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#confirm").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var that = this;

                const act = $(this).attr('data-act');
                const para = $(this).attr('data-para');
                const hash = $(this).attr('data-hash');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/include/ajax/mark_sold.php', // Call delete.php to update the database
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {action: act, para: para, hash: hash},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        $("#fetched").html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                         $(that).closest('div.card').hide();  //to hide div after ajax success
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, statusText, error) {
                        $("#fetched").show();
                        $("#confirmButton").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card border-0 small col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-6 mb-2 px-1">
  <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="/upload/" alt="Card image cap">
<div class="card-body pb-0 pt-2 px-0">
    <h6 class="card-title text-dark text-truncate">title</h6>
</div>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm modalopen"    data-hash="6d8ce77d206011027297b693be999704" data-para="A4IxzuRP8ATv">delete</button>
</div>
```

> How do i hide card after confirming in modal

Comment: Here: `url: '/include/ajax/mark_sold.php'`, how do you know what is to delete? I mean, something in your code should be an identification of the element going to be deleted, right? When you click at the delete button, besides showing the modal, you should save the identification, so further you can hide the right element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that your variable `"that"` is not referring to the delete button, but to the confirm button of the dialog, therefore you can't use `closest()` function. At this point, you should use some specific identification for your card/delete button. For example:

```
$('button[data-hash="'+hash+'"]') .closest('div.card').hide();
```

Another point that I don't see in your code is the transfer of data variables (act, para, hash) to the dialog confirm button. For example your code `$(this).attr('data-hash')` can't reach value from the delete button because `$(this)` refers to the dialog confirm button. The solution to this problem is to pass a unique identifier to the dialog button.

```
$(".deleteBtn").on('click',function(){ //Add on click event to all delete buttons
    $("#confirm").data("hash",$(this).data("hash")); //Pass hash value to dialog confirm button
});

$("#confirm").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var delBtn = $('button[data-hash="'+$(this).data("hash")+'"]'); //Get specific delete button element by passed hash value

    const act = delBtn.attr('data-act'); //Get data variables from the delete button element
    const para = delBtn.attr('data-para');
    const hash = $(this).data("hash");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/include/ajax/mark_sold.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {action: act, para: para, hash: hash},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#fetched").html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            delBtn.closest('div.card').hide();  //Find closest .card element to the specified delete button
        },
        error: function (xhr, statusText, error) {
            $("#fetched").show();
            $("#confirmButton").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Don't forget to add `.deleteBtn` class to your delete buttons.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it worked, i removed transfer of data variables part to make code more readable.